# How can i repeat for-loop after a fixed limit over?

Tags: android, for-loop

I have a for-loop code:

```
try 
    {
      outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/output1.txt");
      Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
      Point point;
      for (int i = 48; i <= 66; i++) 
      {
        point = landmarks.get(i);
        int pointX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
        int pointY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);
        Log.d(TAG, "My points:(" + pointX + "," + pointY + ")");
        point = landmarks.get(i + 1);
        int pointXX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
        int pointYY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);
      canvas.drawLine(pointX, pointY, pointXX, pointYY,mFaceLandmardkPaint);
      out.write(Integer.toString(pointX));
      String h = ",";
      out.write(h);
      out.write(Integer.toString(pointY));
      String j = ",";
      out.write(j);
       }
        out.write("\n");
        out.close();
        }
```

In this i need to start from 48 limit after the first 66 limit gets over.How can i again starts from 48th limit???

Comment: If u do that, when your loop will be broken ?

Comment: Put it into a second loop?

Answer (score 0):

use recursion.
create a method to execute your forloop and at the end of loop call the method again.
like

```
        if(i==65){
        callMethodAgain();
              }
```

and to break the loop store a temp variable to do the count ex.

```
        if(i==65&& temp<2){
             temp++;
        callMethodAgain();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
    for (int i = 48; i <= 66; i++) 
  {
    if(j == 0){
    point = landmarks.get(i);
    int pointX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
    int pointY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);
    Log.d(TAG, "My points:(" + pointX + "," + pointY + ")");
    point = landmarks.get(i + 1);
    int pointXX = (int) (point.x * resizeRatio);
    int pointYY = (int) (point.y * resizeRatio);
    canvas.drawLine(pointX, pointY, pointXX, pointYY,mFaceLandmardkPaint);
    out.write(Integer.toString(pointX));
    String h = ",";
    out.write(h);
    out.write(Integer.toString(pointY));
    String j = ",";
    out.write(j);
    }
    else{
       // do your stuff
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: when repeat for-loop i want to get different points from that loop.How to get that.

Comment: I have updated my code according to your requirement.